# Can iTunes stop playing songs that I have "disliked"?

Tags: itunes

I have songs in my library that I don't care for, and I don't want them to get chosen when iTunes is just randomly picking songs.  It's really annoying to have to go through the list of upcoming songs and delete the ones I don't want to hear.  I've already told iTunes that I don't like some songs.  What's the point in rating songs like that if it doesn't bother to pay attention.

I know I can create playlists, but then I have to specifically tell iTunes to play that playlist.  There are times when iTunes just chooses things to play.  I'm okay with that (in general) but I don't want it to ***ever*** choose things I've specifically told it I don't like.  (E.g. I just hit the play button on my keyboard, because I don't feel like opening iTunes and looking around for a playlist.)

I know I can "uncheck" songs too, but before Loving and Disliking were added to iTunes I worked out a system of exactly what every star rating meant, and what unchecking a song meant.  It has a specific meaning in my system, and this would break my system.

I can also delete these songs from my library, but I don't necessarily want to do that either.  Just because I *generally* don't want to hear them doesn't mean there will never be a time when they are needed or wanted (by someone else in my family, if not by me).

I just want iTunes to do what seems like the obvious thing—never choose songs I've told it I don't like.  Is there a way to do that?